# Printing out a table made in .js to html

Tags: javascript, html-table

I'm new to javascript (I can grasp the basics and the functionality of the language, but lack the "comforting" feeling whilst using it) and there is a project that I've invisioned. The project is supposed to resemble a finished product which in this case is the admin page for a restaurant owner and when the "owner" or admin would click on employees s/he would be able to get those tables printed out based on the "fake database" that was created in javascript.

I've first created a .js file which contains an Array (in this case EmployeeModule.js). Then I proceeded to create another .js file (called employee.js) which reads the data from EmployeeModule.js and sorts it into a table.

Here comes the problem... I am unsure on how to make the employee.js print the data into the HTML. Could anyone assist me with my problem?

```
______________________________________
HTML
______________________________________
<!-- Employee table heading -->
<table style="width:100%" class="table" id="table-employees">

   <!-- Employee.js prints here -->
  
</table>

______________________________________
EmployeeModule.js
______________________________________

const EmployeeModule = ( function(){
    
    const employeeArray = [

        {
            name: "Jane Doe",
            address: "Example Alley 1",
            phoneNumber: "46983312",
            revenue: 15392,
            salary: 188,
            position: "Part-time"

        },
        {
            name: "John Doe",
            address: "The Big Street 5",
            phoneNumber: "92591093",
            revenue: 32574,
            salary: 192,
            position: "Full-time"
        },
        

    ];
    
    const getAll = () => employeeArray;

    return {getAll};

    
})

export default EmployeeModule;

______________________________________
employee.js
______________________________________

const printEmployees = () => {

    let htmlTxt = `
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Revenue</th> 
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Phone Number</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    `;


    EmployeeModule.getAll().forEach(employee => {

        htmlTxt += `
        
            <tr>
                <td class="pt-5"> <img src="images/employee-images/${employee.img}" width="10%"> ${employee.name}</td>
                <td class="pt-5">${employee.revenue},-</td>
                <td class="pt-5">${employee.salary}</td>
                <td class="pt-5">${employee.position}</td>
                <td class="pt-5">${employee.address}</td>
                <td class="pt-5">${employee.phoneNumber}</td>
            </tr>
            
        `;

    })

    tableEmployees.innerHTML = htmlTxt;

}

printEmployee();
```

Comment: do not include `htmlTxt` inside `forEach`, table head is used only one time at the top of the table, and you are including it before each row with `forEach`. However, what is the output? At EmployeeModule you can  simply return `employeeArray`, and try without `getAll`

Comment: Have highlighted 2 minor mistakes  in code. Look once hope it will help you. Also have added updated code hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

One issue I observed is in `employee.js` is in function definition `cont printEmployees` and function you are invoking is `printEmployee()`. Seems like just a Typo error!

Also `EmployeeModule` is function so following statement should be as `EmployeeModule().getAll()` not `EmployeeModule.getAll()` see example as follows:

```
  EmployeeModule()
    .getAll()
    .forEach((employee) => {
      htmlTxt += `
      
          <tr>
              <td class="pt-5"> <img src="images/employee-images/${employee.img}" width="10%"> ${employee.name}</td>
              <td class="pt-5">${employee.revenue},-</td>
              <td class="pt-5">${employee.salary}</td>
              <td class="pt-5">${employee.position}</td>
              <td class="pt-5">${employee.address}</td>
              <td class="pt-5">${employee.phoneNumber}</td>
          </tr>
          
      `;
    });
```

in `HTML` file :

```
<table style="width:100%" class="table" id="table-employees">

   <!-- Employee.js prints here -->
  
</table>
<script type="module" defer src="./employee.js"></script>
```

`employee.js`

```
import EmployeeModule from "./EmployeeModule.js";


const tableEmployees = document.querySelector("#table-employees");


const printEmployee = () => {
  let htmlTxt = `
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Revenue</th> 
          <th>Salary</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>Phone Number</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  `;

  EmployeeModule()
    .getAll()
    .forEach((employee) => {
      htmlTxt += `
      
          <tr>
              <td class="pt-5"> <img src="images/employee-images/${employee.img}" width="10%"> ${employee.name}</td>
              <td class="pt-5">${employee.revenue},-</td>
              <td class="pt-5">${employee.salary}</td>
              <td class="pt-5">${employee.position}</td>
              <td class="pt-5">${employee.address}</td>
              <td class="pt-5">${employee.phoneNumber}</td>
          </tr>
          
      `;
    });

  tableEmployees.innerHTML = htmlTxt;
};

printEmployee();
```

`EmployeeModule.js`

---

```
const EmployeeModule = ( function(){
    
    const employeeArray = [

        {
            name: "Jane Doe",
            address: "Example Alley 1",
            phoneNumber: "46983312",
            revenue: 15392,
            salary: 188,
            position: "Part-time"

        },
        {
            name: "John Doe",
            address: "The Big Street 5",
            phoneNumber: "92591093",
            revenue: 32574,
            salary: 192,
            position: "Full-time"
        },
        

    ];
    
    const getAll = () => employeeArray;

    return {getAll};

    
})

export default EmployeeModule;
```

Comment: Thank you for your well-thought-out answer. It worked out just like I've envisioned it!

Answer (score 0):

1. You should import `EmployeeModule.js` in the top of `employee.js`, just like this:

   ```js
   import EmployeeModule from "./EmployeeModule.js";
   ```
2. To let the script be loaded in HTML, you should place the following line to your  block:

   ```html
   <script type="module" src="./employee.js"></script>
   ```

   When using `type="module"`, you should start a HTTP server serving the HTML, otherwise you would encounter the CORS problem.
3. The reason why it couldn't work should be the undefined `tableEmployees`. To select the `#tableEmployees`, which represents the element with its id `tableEmployees`, and define it:

   ```js
   const tableEmployees = document.querySelector("#table-employees");
   ```

   You can also try the `document.getElementById()`, which is less powerful but faster.

Answer (score 0):

there are few changes in javascript. it should work.

```
      const EmployeeModule = function () {
        const employeeArray = [
          {
            name: 'Jane Doe',
            address: 'Example Alley 1',
            phoneNumber: '46983312',
            revenue: 15392,
            salary: 188,
            position: 'Part-time',
          },
          {
            name: 'John Doe',
            address: 'The Big Street 5',
            phoneNumber: '92591093',
            revenue: 32574,
            salary: 192,
            position: 'Full-time',
          },
        ];


        return employeeArray;
      };



      const printEmployees = () => {
        let htmlTxt = `
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Revenue</th> 
                    <th>Salary</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Phone Number</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            `;
        EmployeeModule().forEach((employee) => {
          htmlTxt += `
            
                <tr>
                    <td class="pt-5"> <img src="images/employee-images/${employee.img}" width="10%"> ${employee.name}</td>
                    <td class="pt-5">${employee.revenue},-</td>
                    <td class="pt-5">${employee.salary}</td>
                    <td class="pt-5">${employee.position}</td>
                    <td class="pt-5">${employee.address}</td>
                    <td class="pt-5">${employee.phoneNumber}</td>
                </tr>
                
            `;
          });
          document
            .querySelector('#table-employees')
            .insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlTxt);
        };

        printEmployees();
```